# ion-input Can't bind to 'errorStateMatcher'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to duplicate some of my working angular code into an Ionic project and I am getting the following error.  Can I not use an ErrorStateMatcher in Ionic?  Any suggestions on how to resolve the error?

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'errorStateMatcher' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.
1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component and it has 'errorStateMatcher' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("="password" [(ngModel)]="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm" formControlName="confirmPassword"  [ERROR ->][errorStateMatcher]="matcher"></ion-input>
            <div *ngFor="let validation of memberValidatio"): ng:///RegisterPageModule/RegisterPage.html@65:125



 <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm" formControlName="confirmPassword"  [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ErrorStateMatcher is defined in @angular/material library. Make sure you add the library and import the necessary modules.

> The mat-form-field allows you to associate error messages with your
>   matInput. By default, these error messages are shown when the control
>   is invalid and either the user has interacted with (touched) the
>   element or the parent form has been submitted. If you wish to override
>   this behavior (e.g. to show the error as soon as the invalid control
>   is dirty or when a parent form group is invalid), you can use the
>   errorStateMatcher property of the matInput

For more information see: [Getting Started with Angular Material in Ionic 4](https://devdactic.com/angular-material-ionic-4/)

Comment: You got it.  I just realized just before I saw your message.